# getSupportActionBar() in AppCompatActivity cannot be applied to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, androidx

I am getting an error while developing the toolbar I have searched solution on the internet and dint gets any solution working as I am new to android development.

I have tried to change the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` to `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar` then I am getting an error as v7 cannot be resolved

main Activity

```
   package com.nanb.chaton;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

   import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private Toolbar main_toolbar;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar main_toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar(main_toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ChatOn");
     }
   }
```

I am getting an error in the `getSupportActionBar` it says that it `cannot be applied with AppCompatActivity to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: I assume u need `setSupportActionBar(main_toolbar)` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#getSupportActionBar()):

```
getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of `getSupportActionBar(toolbar);` which **doesn't** exist.

Instead if you would like to [set the actionbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)) you have to use:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Hi @AcademyforBrilliance. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add Back button in Your toolbar.

Use this code is may help you:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Toolbar toolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }

    //Must use this, if you are using- androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### Toolbar toolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

### toolbar.setTitle(" ");

Comment: if u have set your toolbar in action bar you can give blank title in getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");